# django shows error like 'Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?'

Tags: python, django

following code is from views.py it fetch the profile which is a extension of user module in django also it passes that profile to html as a dictionary.

views.py

```
def render_add_req(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'add_item_request.html', {'profile': profile})
```

This is the code from html to be rendered and in this I am using is_admin attribute of profile object to determine whether the given user is admin or staff and after that I am determining which bases template to be extend with that html depending on user.

add_item_request.html

```
{% if profile.is_admin == 'a' %}
    {% extends 'admin_base.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% extends 'staff_base.html' %}
{% endif %}


{% block title %}
Item Req : Add
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
Item Req : Add
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You cannot put `extends` in an `if-else`. Check [Python / Django - If statement in template around extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043117/python-django-if-statement-in-template-around-extends)

Comment: thank you @AbdulAzizBarkat for your instant and helpful reply, can you suggest me how i can extends different base template depending on different user type in single html page. thanks again! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081901/8401179  check this out

Comment: @susmitdeshpande a simple way would be to pass the template name in the context as `extends` can use a variable name so passing something like `{'template_name': 'admin_base.html', ...}` and in the template `{% extends template_name %}`

Comment: you can check an user's category from views and render seperate template for admin and normal users

Comment: thanks @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM now I know exactly where I was wrong and got the solution. thank again :)

Comment: also thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat now I got it.

Comment: have posted the the summary separately cause it might be helpful for others just incase..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included answers [from comments] of : Abdul Aziz Barkat

You cannot put extends in an if-else.

Check,
[python / django - if statement in template around extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043117/python-django-if-statement-in-template-around-extends)

[Django {% with %} tags within {% if %} {% else %} tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081901/8401179)

**Q how can I extend different base template depending on different user type in single html page ?**

1 a simple way would be to pass the template name in the context as extends can use a variable name so passing something like {'template_name': 'admin_base.html', ...} and in the template {% extends template_name %}

2 Check an user's category from views and render seperate template for admin and normal users