# Python: How can I change the title of a page in Django based on variable?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, variables, with-statement

I am working with a Django app which uses the same template for different 'pages'--basically, the page can either be a "Create Entry" page or an "Edit Entry" page. The page changes based on the following parameters:

```
{% if props.data.id %}
 Edit
{% else %}
 Create
{% endif %}
```

The logic being: if an id exists for this entry, the page will display as a Edit page. Otherwise, the page will display as a Create page.

I would like the title of the page to change depending on the same parameters. So the two versions of the page should be:

```
Create Entry
Edit Entry
```

Here's the code I'm currently trying:

```
{% if props.data.id %}
 {% with action='Edit' %}
 {% endwith %}
{% else %}
 {% with action='Create' %} 
 {% endwith %}
{% endif %}

{% block title %} {{ action }} Entry {% endblock %}
```

I haven't gotten this to work yet. Am I on the right track? I was using 'with' since that seems to be the recommended way to set variables in Django, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) mentions:

> The populated variable is only available between the {% with %} and {% endwith %} tags.

You don't really need to set a variable for this, you can directly do:

```
{% block title %} {% if props.data.id %} Edit {% else %} Create {% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

---

This is not really required for a simple title swap, but you could also pass in a variable as part of the template context like:

```
action = 'Edit' if props.data.id else 'Create'
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'action': action })
```

and then you'll be able to use it as `{{ action }}` in the entire template.

For more complicated logic or behavior, you can check out the suggestions at this question - [Django {% with %} tags within {% if %} {% else %} tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079804/django-with-tags-within-if-else-tags)